# Logistic regression AIC likelihood function and other outputs interpretation

Tags: regression, logistic, python, aic

I have created a logistic regression model using statsmodels in python.
My model has 5 input variables that characterise properties of hillslopes (e.g. mean slope angle, curvature etc) and these are related to a measure of stability.

The number of model inputs stays the same each time. BUT I change the slope size (its a parameter in another program used to make hillslopes on a DEM). So the slopes increase in size 100, 400, 700 etc.

The table below lists the slope sizes and model outputs I need including:
AIC, AUC (ROC), Mc Fadden psuedo R and the p-value of the chi-sqaure test between the log-likelihood of the model (L) and that of the null-model.

I am trying to evaluate which slope size is optimal in terms of the model outputs. 
I understand the interpretation of AUC, R and p-value (i know i shouldnt really use R), but AIC is causing some confusion.

I get that in general terms, lower AIC values indicate the less complex models and increased goodness of fit. As the number of variables (k) used stays the same, AIC must be reducing with slope size due to increasing log-likelood.

So how would I choose between, say a low AIC value and a significant p-value < 0.05. Could I choose size = 1300 as it offers the lowest AIC with a  significant p?

```
 Size   AIC     AUC     R       p-value
 100    107.04  0.86    0.37    0.000
 400    88.38   0.86    0.32    0.008
 700    79.04   0.84    0.31    0.040
 1000   70.29   0.83    0.35    0.023
 1300   65.29   0.84    0.36    0.016
 1600   61.40   0.84    0.33    0.080
```

Comment: What are you hoping to use this model for?

Comment: The modelled probability is used as an indicator of slope stability. So wether or not a slope is stable [0] or susceptible to collapse [1]. I want to determine which slope size produces the best fitting model.